What do I do if my 'question' had more than one part and people have only replied to one part and not another?
Here, I am referring to the translating or parsing of a  phrase or sentence, for example.
Do I comment on his or her answer or am I only allowed to comment about someone else's comment?
Do I make a separate comment about my own post, or do I add a diplomatically worded comment to it as an edit? How best to do it within acceptable guidelines?
For me to point out that half of my question has been ignored (more than once) seems churlish in this instance but what to do when someone gives an answer that I myself have already supplied in the body of my post?
I have read that I cannot repost the same question but, may I reformulate the part of the question that went unanswered and re-submit it?

We seem to be talking about Can somebody please help me to parse the phrase, '挑起满满的一担...'?  It seems the two parts are (a) how is 的 being used, and (b) how is 担 pronounced, where (b) seems adequately answered [担 is functioning as a measure word, so is 4-th tone] but (a) isn't directly mentioned in either answer.
In general, this is one of the reasons why it's important to ask a single, pin-pointed question.  I.e., don't ask questions with multiple parts.  (There's even a close reason for this: "Needs more focus", but this is mostly used in severe cases.)  If someone has multiple questions (even if it's about the same sentence), they can just ask them one by one, ideally first understanding the answers to one question before asking the next (in case the answer to one question affects how another question is asked).
It looks like a reasonable option here is to delete the unanswered sub-question ["(a)"] from the question (so the answers remain correct), and ask a separate question about it.  (This only works here because this part hasn't been answered.)
